# Password doesn't work for Synaptic Package Manager when started from Gnome panel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, gnome, synaptic-pkg-mgr

When I navigate to System->Administration->Synaptic Package Manager it will prompt me for a password. The problem is that it always says I entered the wrong password.

If I run the command "gksudo synaptic" from the console, the password I enter works fine and Synaptic starts with no issues.

I'm guessing I configured something improperly when setting up the OS. Any ideas to get Synaptic to work from the Gnome panel?

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Are you an admin user?  If not, are you entering the admin password or yours?

Comment: @chance Yes, I am an administrator.

Comment: Argh, this happens to me too! I end up always starting synaptic via sudo from a terminal when I want to use it. Funny thing: when `gnome-settings-daemon` isn't running, `gksu` and `synaptic` work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu 10.04, the Synaptic menu entry calls `gksu --description /usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop /usr/sbin/synaptic`  Did you enable the root user?  If you did, you either want to use the root password or change the menu to `gksudo` or add `--sudo-mode` to the current menu entry.

Answer (score 2):

This might help :

1. Ensure that gconf-editor is
   installed
2. Press Alt-F2 and run gconf-editor
3. Go to apps > gksu and tick the
   'sudo-mode' box
4. Try Synaptic again.